# How can I add a new field in YAML using bash script?

Tags: bash, yaml

I want to add a field to my existing yaml file. How can I do that in bash script?

A YAML file sample:

```yaml
field1:
- name: "a"
  env:
    x1: "a"
```

I just want to add `new-key` under env.

Expected file:

```yaml
field1:
- name: "a"
  env:
    x1: "a"
    new-key: "new-value"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: As above, AND will you always be appending to the end of the file? If not, please update your sample data and output. Good luck.

Comment: Have a look at specialized commands like `yq`.

Comment: Like @shellter said, if you only append at the end of the file, simply do `echo "    new-key: \"new-value\" >>file.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You may use sed as shown below

Explanation:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] - edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)

a - Append mode

$(printf '\%2s') - add desired spaces
```

Execution:

```
$ sed  -i "/x1:/a$(printf '\%2s')  new-key: \"new-value\"" test.txt

$ cat test.txt
field1:
- name: "a"
  env:
    x1: "a"
    new-key: "new-value"
```

Comment: this didn't work for me.

Comment: Post your bash script so I can take a look